# Are there any errors that are not controlled by Quiet?

Tags: warning-messages, quiet

I believed that using Quiet, all message output would be controlled.

```
Quiet@Plot3D[x, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, a}]
Quiet@ContourPlot[x + y == 1, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, a}]
```

[image]
[image]

However, this is not the case in the example above.

Is that the way it is? Or is it a bug? I am using 13.3.

Of course, if Off is used, the message output disappears.

However, in addition to Plot3D, ContourPlot and ParametricPlot3D were found in this phenomenon.

I want to effectively turn on and off these kinds of messages.

Comment: "is it a bug?" - sure looks like one to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like `Quiet` works correctly at first, but then when it returns the expression, `Plot3D` is still there and another evaluation is attempted for some reason. See, for example:

```
Quiet @ With[{
    eval = Plot3D[x, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, a}]
},
    Hold[eval]
]
```

Here the returned expression is wrapped in Hold before `Quiet` expires, so no further evaluation can be attempted. This successfully removes all messages. So the moral of the story is that you either have to Hold the failed plot or replace it with some kind of failure object. For example:

```
Quiet[
 ResourceFunction["FailIfUnevaluated"] @ Plot3D[x, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, a}]
]
```

## Edit

or, as pointed out by Domen in the comment below:

```
Quiet[Check[Plot3D[x, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, a}], $Failed]]
```

Comment: What about using `Check`? For example: `Quiet[Check[Plot3D[x, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, a}], $Failed]]`

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, `Check`  will work as well. Forgot about that one.